# Extending GCC for memory management

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I need to extend GCC compiler for memory management for a huge c++ project, but I have no idea what to start with, I need some documentation about how gcc allocates memory, and also a plug-in framework, that can help me do this.
Thanks,

Comment: What memory management are you talking about? GCCs internal memory management during compilation? Also I believe that prior to GCC 5.0 there is no easy way to develope plugins for gcc, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: What I meant by memory management is how gcc allocates memory for objects, strings and vectors ...

Comment: GCC doesn't handle memory management - the C++ new and delete are (typically) wrappers for `malloc`/`free` functions - with exception handling semantics - provided by the C++ library. You need to be more specific. This question is vague to the point of being meaningless.

Comment: @Othman the link you provided talks about C++ `allocator` classes, which are completely defined by the library code. No need to mess with the compiler, not the standard library. If you want to e.g. use a pool allocator for all your objects, just google "custom allocator C++" and you will get a plethora of web pages on the subject. If you have a specific question related to a problem in your implementation, feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: The link actually was not a good answer, I know that I am not being clear here, but I am trying. Let me explain :    for example if I declare a 2 pointers in c++ `int *i; int *j`, when I dump the gimple tree, I have this : `int D.20827; int D.20828; ... ` , what I want to know is why did the compiler choose the adresses 20828 and 20827 and how can I change that, I am not trying to change the implementation, It's a 10M lines project, I working only on the compiler

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what is your problem.
You probably mean some pluggable library which optimizes/controlls allocation.

You may check google tcmalloc and maybe, to see what is possible, have a look at Boehm–Demers–Weiser allocator.

Comment: That's not what I am looking for, as I said I need to extend gcc, add a new pass to it.